# Causality for cross sectional data

Tags: causality, cross-section

I have been reading and reading about causality for cross-sectional datasets (different variables including only ONE-YEAR information) and I am still confused...
CAN WE analyze causality in one-year data ? If so, how?
Could you share some scientific works in that case testing this?
Thank you !

Comment: What have you been reading on this topic that's not clear?

Comment: Richard, thanks for your answer. I've read that it is possible to assess causality with one-year data but other scholars do not agree and I do not find how to test it.